# how to extract data corresponding query

Tags: mysql

how to extract data corresponding query :
`"multiple_option_id=10"` and `"multiple_option_id=1074"` and return `"product_id"` that corresponds this query?

[link to img](http://s16.postimg.org/mxg81fbd1/dasdsa.png)

Answer (score 1):

This has 2 possibilities

- Get the `product_id` which has `multiple_option_id` either 10 or 1024
- Get the `product_id` which has `multiple_option_id` both 10 or 1024

For the first case its fairly simple

```
select product_id from table_name 
where multiple_option_id in (10,1024)
```

And for the 2nd case it would be

```
select product_id from table_name 
where multiple_option_id in (10,1024) 
group by product_id having count(*) = 2
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that it's the 2nd case that the OP is after.

Answer (score 0):

```
 select product_id from table 
 where multiple_option_id in (10,1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select product_id from table where multiple_option_id= 10 or multiple_option_id = 1024;
```

Comment: I appreciate that it wasn't much of a question, but this isn't much of an answer. It lacks explanation and besides, it isn't what the OP is after.